# Using PIVOT on a calendar in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I have the following problem: I need to implement a calendar using SQL Server 2005. Here's an example of what my stored procedure gives me so far:

```
TIME  |    DATE    |  CALENDAR_ID |  SUBJECT  |  NOTES  | STATUS_ID
===================================================================
09:00 | 19/08/2013 | 1            | SUBJECT 1 | NOTES 1 | 1
10:00 | 19/08/2013 | 2            | SUBJECT 2 | NOTES 2 | 2
11:00 | 19/08/2013 | 3            | SUBJECT 3 | NOTES 3 | 3
12:00 | 19/08/2013 | 4            | SUBJECT 4 | NOTES 4 | 1
09:00 | 20/08/2013 | 5            | SUBJECT 5 | NOTES 5 | 4
10:00 | 20/08/2013 | 6            | SUBJECT 6 | NOTES 6 | 3
11:00 | 20/08/2013 | 7            | SUBJECT 7 | NOTES 7 | 1
12:00 | 20/08/2013 | 8            | SUBJECT 8 | NOTES 8 | 1
```

But I'd like to display it like this:

```
TIME  | 19/08/2013 | 20/08/2013
===============================
09:00 | SUBJECT 1  | SUBJECT 5
10:00 | SUBJECT 2  | SUBJECT 6
11:00 | SUBJECT 3  | SUBJECT 7
12:00 | SUBJECT 4  | SUBJECT 8
```

I know about the PIVOT function in SQL Server which seems to be useful for these cases, and I searched for examples and explanations, but I still don't understand completely. Besides, so far I've seen only examples like getting the total sum of sales per month; I'm not sure my calendar could use the same logic (or even if I can do what I intend to do using PIVOT). Anyway, could someone point me in the right direction about my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the PIVOT function to convert the rows of data into columns.  You will just use the aggregate function `max` or `min` to select the `subject` for each date.  If you have a limited number of dates that you want to convert into columns then you can hard-code the query:

```
select [time], [19/08/2013], [20/08/2013]
from
(
  select [time], [date], subject
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(subject)
  for [date] in ([19/08/2013], [20/08/2013])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b25de/4)

But if you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATE) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [time], ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select [time], [date], subject
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(subject)
                for [date] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b25de/5). Both will give a result:

```
|  TIME | 19/08/2013 | 20/08/2013 |
-----------------------------------
| 09:00 |  SUBJECT 1 |  SUBJECT 5 |
| 10:00 |  SUBJECT 2 |  SUBJECT 6 |
| 11:00 |  SUBJECT 3 |  SUBJECT 7 |
| 12:00 |  SUBJECT 4 |  SUBJECT 8 |
```